# Format an array of Objects to a HTML table

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am working in angular and trying to format an API response into a simple HTML table in Angular, this process is generally straightforward when the data is single level eg.

```
{
  property-1: value-1
  property-2: value-2
  .
  .
  .
  property-n: value-n
}
```

However my array of Objects looks something like this:

```
[
 index: index_1
 value: {
    property-1: value-1
    property-2: value-2
    property-3: value-3
  },
  index: index_1
  value: {
    property-1: value-1
    property-2: value-2
    property-3: value-3
  },
  index : index_2
  value : {
    property-1: value-1
    property-2: value-2
    property-3: value-3
    property-4: value-4
  }
]
```

What I am hoping to achieve is one table for each index, so index_1 would get one table with column names matching the keys for index_1 (they are always going to be the same keys when the index is the same) and table data being all the data from the different objects in side the main object (if that makes sense)

#### Gap in Understanding

Where I am having trouble is that the format of the API response is a little weird in that index_1 can show up for as many times as a result for index_1 is spit out, so I don't think I can use a simple ngFor, now there may be a better way for me to format my data from the API response, at the moment this is how I am going about it:

```js
let results: any[][] = await this.searchAllIndexes(searchTerm);
      
results.forEach(i => i.forEach(j => {
  let json = {
    index: j._index,
    value: j._source //j._source is an object itself
  }
  result.push(json) //result is a local array of objects inside the function
}))
      
this.resultObject = result; //this.result is an array of objects
```

Below is a console log of my output for reference:

[image: Console log of result variable]

Comment: Can you provide a sample input-output? Two property with the same name simply cannot exist, they'll be merged instead into one object overriding any value with the latter, so your input is either wrong or simply misleading

Comment: Ahh I can see where it's misleading I should have noted that the above JSON example is an array of Objects, and fixed my notation, let me make the necessary edits and maybe that'll make it make more sense, sorry about that

Comment: @kmp Changed question title and the misleading stuff above, this is a better reflection of my output

Comment: Still not valid json. It would help if you could post the actual data you’re getting back..

Comment: So basically, you want to create a table for each object with the same properties? Like.. if it has the same props, thats a new row

Comment: your question contains invalid json

Comment: Added a screenshot of output of the data I want to put in a table

Comment: your output isn't an array of arrays. it's an array of objects with properties `index` and `value`

Comment: See prior comment where I stated it's array of objects and question title

Comment: you're typing it as an array of arrays, treating it as an array of arrays in your code, and you're giving invalid json in your question. fix your question to be correct if you expect a correct answer.

Comment: edited again, for the typing I've tried array of objects but it won't let me nest the for-each in that scenario

Comment: you can't do a nested forEach if you don't have an array of arrays. lying to the typescript compiler about the typings isn't going to change that.

Comment: Y'all really made me doubt myself, my datatype that I am working IS an array of an array of objects, the only real blunder I made is that the data type is any[][] the reason it is any[][] is so that I can use .index and ._source to because if I use `Object` datatype I am unable to say `Object.index` and `Object._source`

Comment: The picture you posted is the desired input or output? It looks more like an input to me.. And also can you post it with markdown codeblock, so I can copy paste to test algorithms

Comment: Input or output to what exactly, input/output to function? to table? the screenshot is the data that needs to go into the table if that helps

Comment: Input output as in input to be consumed by a function and output is the desired data format, but yes it helps :)

Comment: JSON is a text format. You are working with arrays and objects. Don't conflate the two and you'll be less confused.

Answer (score 0):

### Data formatting

```js
const data = [
  {
    index: "new_index",
    value: {
      PLN_TYP_CD: "S",
      PLN_TYP_DESC: "Disability",
      INSRT_BTCH_ID: 4033598,
      LST_UPDT_BTCH_ID: -1,
      INSRT_TS: "2017-12-06T11:25:47.891258",
    },
  },
  {
    index: "custom_index_5",
    value: {
      PROV_ASGN_ROLE_TYP_CD: "S",
      PROV_ASGN_ROLE_TYP_DESC: "PHYSICIAN IS A SPECIALIST",
      POL_ORIG_SRC_SYS_CD: "NDB",
      PROV_ASGN_ROLE_TYP_NRML_CD: "S",
    },
  },
  {
    index: "custom_index_5",
    value: {
      PROV_ASGN_ROLE_TYP_CD: "S",
      PROV_ASGN_ROLE_TYP_DESC: "SPECIALIST",
      POL_ORIG_SRC_SYS_CD: "CRR",
      PROV_ASGN_ROLE_TYP_NRML_CD: "S",
    },
  },
  {
    index: "custom_index_5",
    value: {
      PROV_ASGN_ROLE_TYP_CD: "S",
      PROV_ASGN_ROLE_TYP_DESC: "PHYSICIAN IS A SPECIALIST",
      POL_ORIG_SRC_SYS_CD: "OXF",
      PROV_ASGN_ROLE_TYP_NRML_CD: "S",
    },
  },
];

function listNames(data) {
  return data
    .map((item) => item.index)
    .filter((val, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(val) === i);
}

function listColumns(tableName, data) {
  const columnObj = data.find((item) => item.index === tableName).value;
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(columnObj);
}

function fillRow(tableData, obj) {
  const row = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < tableData.columns.length; i++) {
    row.push(obj[tableData.columns[i]]);
  }

  tableData.rows.push(row);
}

function formatJSON(data) {
  const output = [];
  const tables = listNames(data);

  for (let i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    const tableData = {
      title: tables[i],
      columns: listColumns(tables[i], data),
      rows: [],
    };

    for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      if (data[j].index === tableData.title) {
        fillRow(tableData, data[j].value);
      }
    }

    output.push(tableData);
  }

  return output;
}

console.log(formatJSON(data));
```

### HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let table of tables">
  <div>{{ table.title }}</div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let column of table.columns">{{ column }}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of table.rows">
        <td *ngFor="let value of row">{{ value }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```